# Access to network drive is denied but only if running web app remotely

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, windows, server

I have recently been tasked with maintaining a website written in VB and .NET 4.0
and I ran into a problem when attempting to access folders/files from a network drive.

If I run locally (http://localhost:8080), I get no problem
[image]

But if I run it remotely, I get this: 
[image]

I have created a web.config file in this directory to enable impersonation as well

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Authentication setting in IIS configuration is set to True.

Anyone has any idea how I should go about this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you give access to the share to the asp.net account IUSR_MACHINENAME as mentioned in the error image?

Comment: I actually haven't. which machine name would that be? machine where the folder is located or the server machine?

Comment: I tried both and none worked